# How to add Content/Type header to file without extension on Apache2

Tags: apache

I want to add a 'Content/Type' header to a JSON file on the root of web directory. How to enforce adding the matching header if the file has no *.json* extension

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your Apache config file:

`<Files "FILENAME">
    ForceType application/json
</Files>`